# like and not like in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a database table with name 'student' and have column 'name'.

I want to retrieve the names of students starting without a title 'miss' but starting with 'miss'.

I did:

```
select name from students where lower(name) like 'miss%' and name not like 'miss %'
```

The above query returns names with title also.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you maybe just need lower() around "name" the second time?  For me with Postgres 9.5 your query works, if you say "and lower(name) not like 'miss %'